# How to cut a nano SIM out of a 8-pin SIM?

Tags: cellphone, sim, mobile-phones

I have a 8-pin SIM, which I want to cut into a nano SIM (which only has 6 pins).
Looking at the [Wikipedia X-Ray image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/SIM-Card_X-ray_contrast.jpg),  I assume I should cut the lower 2 pins.

Is this correct?

[image: 8-pin SIM]

Comment: Just request a nano SIM from your provider....

Comment: I think the odds of your success are very low.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6T1Mygucak

Comment: Thank you, Bruce. I just cut a 6-pin SIM into nano format without a template and a utility blade instead of scissors

Comment: Why do you suggest this, JonR?

Comment: Why do you think that, Elliot?

Comment: I've done this with a printed template, pliers, and sandpaper. The later is useful both to fix the edges and to make the card thinner (just take a little bit of plastic off its back).
Replacing the card gives better results, and it's always a good plan B if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are the right pads to cut off.

Though, I have to warn you, it is possible to cut that card so that it gets stuck to the phone. Nano-SIM is also thinner than Mini-SIM so you have to slice off some 0.1mm from it to make it fit most phones. Still it is doable, but just be careful not to cut it too small.

Also, the old SIMs might not work well with newer mobile technologies. Depends on your operator.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and the warning.

Comment: With "new mobile technology" you mean all that follows GSM?

Comment: I don't remember was it LTE or WCDMA that requires newer version of SIM card.

Comment: TemeV, the former 8-pin nano SIM shows 4G in the status bar and "Mobile Network Type" LTE  in the settings. Download speed 80 Mbps, upload speed 40 Mbps. I guess the SIM is more than 6 years old.

Comment: Operator is O2 (Germany)

Comment: Well, if it works then you don't have to worry about that